# Syntax for Stored Procedure Parameter

Tags: c#

I have a value which I am trying to add as a parameter to a stored procedure.

The value of this parameter could either be a STRING of "1" or "NULL"

If it's NULL then I want to add the parameter of `DBNull.Value`

If it's "1" I want to add the parameter of 1 (int)

I have tried numerous combinations of syntax but cannot get it right.

This is what I have:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LinkClickedId", (insertValuesSplit[12] == "NULL") ? Convert.ToInt16(insertValuesSplit[12]) : DBNull.Value));
```

But I have a syntax error of

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'short' and 'System.DBNull'
>   Can anyone suggest what the syntax should be please?

Comment: Have you ever read the documentation of [`?:` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)? It says: _Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other._

Comment: By the way, I think you should invert the values assigned to the true/false conditions

Answer (score 1):

Try casting it to an object:

```
(object) Convert.ToInt16(insertValuesSplit[12])
```

The problem is that there is no common type that your ternary operator can discern between `Convert.ToInt16(insertValuesSplit[12])` and `DBNull.Value`, but if you cast your value to an `object`, then it works because there *is* an implicit conversion between `DBNull.Value` and `object`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(insertValuesSplit[12] == "NULL") ? Convert.ToInt16(insertValuesSplit[12]) : DBNull.Value)
```

Short-hand if-statements have to return the same type.

`Convert.ToInt16(insertValuesSplit[12])` returns a `short`

`DBNull.Value` returns an `Object`

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator is an expression, and as such it has a type. The compiler tries to determine this type but fails because your true-case is a `short` but your false-case a `DBNull`.

You have to explicitly cast one of them to `object` to make it work, e.g.
`(object) Convert.ToInt16(insertValuesSplit[12])`.

Answer (score 0):

The true and false sub-expressions of your conditional operator have types DbNull and Int16.

You probably need to cast the results to the only common base type: `object`.

PS. I think you have the condition reversed: if "NULL" you want `DBNUll` and not the parse.